# weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 32 seconds

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, weblogic11g

I have following configuration

```
OS Sparc 11
OCSG 5.1
Environment : Cluster (Admin+MS), (MS)
Weblogic : 11g
```

Problem:

I have deployed existing running ear from old environment (ocsg 5.1 windows ) to my new environment sparc 11 ocsg 5.1. I am facing following issue

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction Rolledback.: weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 32 seconds
BEA1-0009181AB1D7057B1ADE
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.wakeUp(ServerTransactionImpl.java:1788)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionManagerImpl.processTimedOutTransactions(ServerTransactionManagerImpl.java:1676) at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionManagerImpl.wakeUp(TransactionManagerImpl.java:1988)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionManagerImpl.wakeUp(ServerTransactionManagerImpl.java:1586)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.WLSTimer.timerExpired(WLSTimer.java:35)
    at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:273)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
    nested exception is: weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 32 seconds
    BEA1-0009181AB1D7057B1ADE
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.EJBRuntimeUtils.throwEJBException(EJBRuntimeUtils.java:156)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.postInvoke1(BaseLocalObject.java:595)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.__WL_postInvokeTxRetry(BaseLocalObject.java:455)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:52)
    at com.warid.es.vasactivation.VasManagerServer_82gq0g_VasManagerServerLocalImpl.getBalanceDate(Unknown Source)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    Caused By: weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 32 seconds
    BEA1-0009181AB1D7057B1ADE
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.wakeUp(ServerTransactionImpl.java:1788)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionManagerImpl.processTimedOutTransactions(ServerTransactionManagerImpl.java:1676)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionManagerImpl.wakeUp(TransactionManagerImpl.java:1988)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionManagerImpl.wakeUp(ServerTransactionManagerImpl.java:1586)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.WLSTimer.timerExpired(WLSTimer.java:35)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I have seen on my console every thing is processed fine but no response is sent back to client which result in connection timeout issue.

Answer (score 9):

Try increasing the domain's JTA Timeout : open the weblogic console, go to domain, services, JTA ; Change 'Timeout Seconds' from 30 to 3000. 
In config.xml this should show as:

```
<JTA
    TimeoutSeconds="300"

/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which worked for me, because I could not change the global configuration for Weblogic, was to annotate my method with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)`.
Your JPA method calls will still work inside this method(tested) and values will still get persisted into the DB.